# user space library in Linux kernel modal - for testing

Tags: c, linux

I know you shouldn't and it is bad practice etc. but is it possible to include a c userspace library in a kernel module?

I am writing the module for my own purposes to test some things and it will never be published or used by anyone else. I just want a quick hack not worrying about good practices.

(specifically I would like to use the __int128 datatype provided by gcc included in `<stdint.h>`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C library is first of all a collection of functions, there is no real distinction between "user-space" and "kernel-space". However, using a dynamic shared library is not straight possible in kernel space, since there is no suitable dynamic loader for this. Indeed, loading the kernel-module itself is some kind of dynamic loading, but the module itself cannot load another shared library in turn.

However, it should be possible to link code from a static library (.a) to your kernel module. This code then becomes integral part of your kernel module itself and should work in kernelspace as in userspace, as long as it doesn't depend on external symbols, which are not present in kernel space (especially symbols of the libc, for example).